# nginx fallback if rewrite fails

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

my folder structure:

/var/www/puenktchenunda/public/img/subjects

/var/www/puenktchenunda/public/img/subjects_min

subjects contains that "raw" files. Subjects_min contains compressed images that will be created periodically. The URL call will go to subjects:

/img/subjects/img1.png

What should happen:

1. rewrite to subjects_min
2. if /img/subjects_min/img1.png does exist, serve it
3. if /img/subjects_min/img1.png does not exist, serve image from /img/subjects/img1.png

Step 1 and 2 work out fine. That works with this location block:

```
location ~* ^.*\/img\/sujets\/.*.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif) {

    root /var/www/puenktchenunda/public;
    rewrite /img/sujets/(.*)$ /img/sujets_min/$1;
    #try_files /img/sujets_min/$URI /img/sujet/$URI;
```

}

But I'm not really sure how to accomplish the rest. Any ideas?

**Update**

This is my current version. This works fine, except for the sujets_big location block. There are some issues with $1 at the end. The whole block expression is added after $1 instead of just the expression in brackets.

```
location ~ /img/sujets/(.*.png)$ {
    root /var/www/puenktchenunda/public/;
    try_files /img/sujets_min/$1 /img/sujets_big/$1;
}


location ~ /img/sujets_big/(.*.png)$ {
    root /var/www/puenktchenunda/public/img/sujets/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this logic

```
location ~* ^/img/subjects/([\w\-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$ {

    root /var/www/puenktchenunda/public;

    set $imgfilename /img/subjects_min/$1;

    if (-f $document_root$imgfilename) {

        rewrite . $imgfilename break;

    }

}
```

Comment: hm, it says "nginx: [emerg] unknown "root" variable"

Comment: and when I replace $root with the full path it has issues with appending too much, incl. the whole expression in the location.

Comment: @rapsli try variable instead of `$1`. Edited with `$document_root`.